# Custom post type with pagenavigation not working

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, themes

I have been struggling all night to make this work, but it seems that I can't find the problem. I'm using Bootstrap to make a new theme, and along with it, I have a small piece of code for custom page navigation, and it seems to work fine with basic WordPess post list.

But I have added a new custom post type called gallery, and I can't find a solution on how to list all the posts in the gallery custom post type and make pagination work. So far, I have made a new file called archive-galleries.php, and it lists all the posts with the gallery custom post type, but it won't go to the second page. I get the error `404 not found`.

Here is the code of archive-galleries.php page

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar('top'); ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
    <?php the_post(); ?>
    <h3 class="text-error"><?php _e('Latest image galleries', 'vt-translate'); ?></h3>
    <?php $count = 0;
    $paged = intval(get_query_var('paged'));
    $paged = ($paged) ? $paged : 1; 

    $query_arguments = array(
    'post_type' => 'galleries',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'paged' => $paged,
    );
    // Query posts
    query_posts( $query_arguments );
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $open = !($count%4) ? '<div class="row">' : '';
    $close = !($count%4) && $count ? '</div>' : '';
    echo $close.$open;
    ?>
        <div class="span2">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <img class="thumb" data-src="holder.js/160x250" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/inc/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true); ?>&h=250&w=160&zc=1" />
            </a>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <h6>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php trim_title(); ?></a>
            </h6>
        </div>
    <?php 
    $count++;
    endwhile; 
    echo $count ? '</div>' : '';
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
            <?php get_sidebar('pageright'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">
    <?php page_navi(); ?>
</div><!-- #nav-below -->
<?php get_sidebar('belownavigation'); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And here is the custom code I used for pagination, located in the functions.php file:

```
//Wordpress page navigation with numbers
function page_navi($before = '', $after = '') {
    global $wpdb, $wp_query;
    $request = $wp_query->request;
    $posts_per_page = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));
    $paged = intval(get_query_var('paged'));
    $numposts = $wp_query->found_posts;
    $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if ( $numposts <= $posts_per_page ) { return; }
    if(empty($paged) || $paged == 0) {
        $paged = 1;
    }
    $pages_to_show = 7;
    $pages_to_show_minus_1 = $pages_to_show-1;
    $half_page_start = floor($pages_to_show_minus_1/2);
    $half_page_end = ceil($pages_to_show_minus_1/2);
    $start_page = $paged - $half_page_start;
    if($start_page <= 0) {
        $start_page = 1;
    }
    $end_page = $paged + $half_page_end;
    if(($end_page - $start_page) != $pages_to_show_minus_1) {
        $end_page = $start_page + $pages_to_show_minus_1;
    }
    if($end_page > $max_page) {
        $start_page = $max_page - $pages_to_show_minus_1;
        $end_page = $max_page;
    }
    if($start_page <= 0) {
        $start_page = 1;
    }

    echo $before.'<ul>'."";
    if ($paged > 1) {
        echo '<li class="prev"><a href="'.get_pagenum_link().'" title="First">'.__('&laquo;','vt-translate').'</a></li>';
    }

    $prevposts = get_previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous');
    if($prevposts) { echo '<li>' . $prevposts  . '</li>'; }
    else { echo '<li class="active"><a href="#">&laquo; Previous</a></li>'; }

    for($i = $start_page; $i  <= $end_page; $i++) {
        if($i == $paged) {
            echo '<li class="active"><a href="#">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo '<li class="">';
    next_posts_link('Next &raquo;');
    echo '</li>';
    if ($end_page < $max_page) {
        echo '<li class="next"><a href="'.get_pagenum_link($max_page).'" title="Last">'.__('&raquo;','vt-translate').'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>'.$after."";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution, or it's kinda workaround, for some reason custom post type archive doesn't work same way as default archive.

So for workaround main problem is with permalinks, so i had to use different custom post type name and custom page template.

In my functions.php file i have code where i register custom post type called galleries. But since i wanted to use galleries to list all posts i will name my page like that and i had to add rewrite rule to my custom post type so function that register my custom post type now looks like this.

```
function my_custom_post_product() {
$labels = array(
    'menu_name'             => 'Galleries',
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Posts' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'description'           => 'Add image galleries custom posts',
    'public'                => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields' ),
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'gallery'),
    '_builtin' =>  false
);
register_post_type( 'galleries', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_product' );
```

So instead of galleries my custom post now use gallery slug.

Now to list all posts in my gallery i have used code from archive-galleries.php page and created new page template called page-galleries.php and added code from archive-galleries.php.

Now i just created new page, selected my newly created galleries template and saved page. Added new page to menu and it works.

There is big debate on internet how to make pagination work for custom post type and for some reason it not works as regular archive works, even if it's intended to work native with archive-custom_post_type_slug.php this is only working workaround i have crafted by my self and main problem is which many on internet overlooked (like i did also) is that you can't name page same as post type slug, and archive won't work with permalinks default set.